# What part of yii2 code must be change to update?

Tags: yii2

this code must be update cars and users form database but when operate create new field and not update, what part of them must be change to update a field ?

I using YII2 framework and this code in controller.

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = new JunkForm();
    $cars = CarsForm::find()->all();
    $carDropDown = [];
    foreach ($cars as $car) {
        $carDropDown[$car->id] = $car->car_name . ' (' . $car->car_color . ')';
    }
    $users = UserForm::find()->all();
    $userDropDown = [];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $userDropDown[$user->id] = $user->user_name . ' (' . $user->user_family . ')';
    }
    if ($model->load(yii::$app->request->post())) {
        foreach ($model->carIds as $carId) {
            foreach ($model->userIds as $userId) {
                $oldJunk = JunkForm::find()->where(['users_id' => $userId])->andWhere(['cars_id' => $carId])->one();
                if (empty($oldJunk)) {
                    $newJunk = new JunkForm();
                    $newJunk->cars_id = $carId;
                    $newJunk->users_id = $userId;
                    $newJunk->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $model = new JunkForm();
        return $this->render('junk_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'carDropDown' => $carDropDown,
        'userDropDown' => $userDropDown
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this :

```
$newJunk = new JunkForm();
                    $newJunk->cars_id = $carId;
                    $newJunk->users_id = $userId;
                    $newJunk->save();
```

change to this :

```
$newJunk = JunkForm::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
                    $newJunk->cars_id = $carId;
                    $newJunk->users_id = $userId;
                    $newJunk->save();
```